# Android where can I get image taken by native camera app

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am using native camera app to capture image, And I am not using MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT to specify the path of image. Then how can i get the image using the intent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture images using camera call this intent

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, requestCode);
```

and to handle the callback use onActivityResult function

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

Bitmap mImageBitmap;
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            mImageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                    (Bitmap) extras.get("data"), 100, 100, false);
}
```

mImageBitmap will hold the image that you captured. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey ajay, thanks for answer. I have a question on this,here you have used "data" as a key from intent extras.How would I know that what key would get me image data. And in file explorer where is the image stored.

Comment: hey chitra,
please refer this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
please read through it completly

Comment: when you use the intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, the camera captures an image and returns it, so now to handle the returned data, you can store it by using EXTRA_OUTPUT ,since you are not using that, by running the code i have given you a  small sized image that is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field is directly recieved by ur code and you can use it as you please

Comment: hey ajay,thanks for reply. I got it now.  Can you please suggest me Whether I should use native camera app or use the Camera API for image capturing.

Comment: i dont get you, what do you wanna achieve?

Comment: Actually I want to capture images and video,as per android documentation there are two ways to achieve it, through the Camera API or camera Intent. So can you suggest me which would be better option. Right now I am using camera Intent for it.

Comment: It depends on what all operations you want to do, if you wanna use the camera extensively then i suggest you use the camera api else intents will suffice

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14586398/1965084) topic. What do you mean by you are not using the MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT? After can get the image data back via callback and save it as picture in a custom location.

Comment: Actually I have not store picture to custom location so how can I get picture from default location.