# How to create camera button that stores images to gallery?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, camera, gallery

How would I correctly get a buttons intent to take a picture and store that image in the phones gallery? So far i have a button which is in a case structure that says :

else if (v.getId() == R.id.button5)//camera

```
        {

                Intent c  = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(c,1);





        }
```

what should my onActivityResult look like since i am just storing that image to the gallery?

would i have to use something as bundle extras = data.getExtras();?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14725773/909497) answer may be your problems solution. But data.getExtras() returns null in some cases and unfortunately I have not detected all of these cases yet. For example data.getExtras() worked fine on android 2.3 HTC Evo 3D but on android 2.3 Samsung Galaxy SII, it returned null. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to call your startActivityForResult() method like the following:

```
Uri imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new  ContentValues());
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageFileUri);
startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
```

And in the implementation of startActivityForResult() method you have to write the following:

```
// Save the name and description of an image in a ContentValues map.
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(3);
contentValues.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "This is a test title");
contentValues.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, "This is a test description");
contentValues.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
// Add a new record without the bitmap, but with some values set.
// insert() returns the URI of the new record.
Uri imageFileUri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
```