# How to implement camera effect on image capture using camera api in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, camera-api

I am designing a camera app using camera api not camera2 api, which open back camera and on button click it capture image but does not show any effect as like my phone camera app. How can i implement effect when start capturing image it slightly zoom in and zoom out as android native camera app? Please help...

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
```

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot add effects using the camera api as they are done using image manipulation in the native app. You might prefer to use the native app like shown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725291/android-where-can-i-get-image-taken-by-native-camera-app

Comment: Camera api does not provide which you are looking. Either you can use some library to do this or you can write own code

Comment: Can i highlight the object just before capturing the image?